# Creating a button from a subclass not appearing in view

Tags: swift, uibutton, subclass

Will someone *please* explain why the following code is not placing a button in my view?

Button Class

```
class CustomButton: UIButton {

    var button = UIButton()

    func makeButton() {
        button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200)
        button.center = self.center
        button.setTitle("PRESS", for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.buttonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.addSubview(button)
    }
}
```

Main Class

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var button: CustomButton?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        button?.makeButton()
    }

    @objc func buttonPressed() {
        print("woohoo!")
    }
}
```

Comment: The button in VC is nil

Comment: Also, the `CustomButton` logic is odd in that it's both a subclass of `UIButton` and a container for one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to completely redo the `CustomButton` class. It should not have a `button` property. It should initialize itself.

And the setting of the target belongs in the view controller, not the button class.

Updated button code:

```
class CustomButton: UIButton {
    init() {
        super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
        setTitle("PRESS", for: .normal)
        backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Updated view controller:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var button = CustomButton()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(button)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    @objc func buttonPressed() {
        print("woohoo!")
    }
}
```